# convert TB to GB on specific index

Tags: pandas

I wrote such an code. Here i wanted to change all column that constitute TB and GB to single integer. for example if column has 2 TB, this code will delete TB and will keep it as 2. The program works good. What now i want to do is to convert 2TB to 2048 GB so that i can sum all column values. Is there any way to remove TB and make calculation on specific row at the same time?

```
def removeend():
df= pd.read_csv('ExportList.csv')
if df["Used Space"].str.contains("GB | TB").any() or df["Memory Size"].str.contains("GB | TB").any() or df["Host CPU"].str.contains("Hz|MHz|GHz").any():
    df['Used Space'] = df['Used Space'].str.replace(r'GB|TB', '', regex=True)
    df["Memory Size"] = df["Memory Size"].str.replace(r'GB|TB', '', regex=True)
    df['Host CPU'] = df['Host CPU'].str.replace(r'MHz|Hz|GHz', '', regex=True)
    df = df.convert_dtypes()
    df["Used Space"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Used Space"])
    df["Memory Size"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Memory Size"])
    df["Host CPU"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Host CPU"])
else:
    print("Error occured!!!")

return df
```

Comment: Updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: Hi! if your query is solved then you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer(click on the tick to make it green).....thanks

Comment: pls see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 0):

define\create a custom function:

```
def converter(x):
    try:
        return pd.eval(x)
    except:
        return x
```

Finally:

```
cols=["Used Space","Memory Size"]
df[cols]=df[cols].replace({'GB':'','TB':'*1024'},regex=True).applymap(converter)
df["Host CPU"]=df["Host CPU"].replace({'MHz':'','GHz':'*0.001','Hz':'*0.000001'},regex=True).map(converter)
```

Comment: it worked well for Used Space. Now i want to change all CPU frequency to MHz. so i wrote like that but no changes were made.